# SharePoint 2010 archive document library

Tags: 2010, document-library, document, archive

I have SharePoint 2010 and I have a Document library there. The document library has structure like this: yyyy/mm/dd. In 'dd' is items sended at this day. Now, I would like to archive every items older than this year so on the beginning of the year it should run my archive app and archive items.

In the archive should be the same structure (yyyy/mm/dd).

I would like to ask you, what is the best way to do this?

1) write my own app? (propably cmd app and run via task scheduler)
2) SharePoint Information Management Policy (is it possible to do by this)?
3) Create new worklflow in SharePoint Designer (is it possible)?

What is the best way to archive my document library?

Thanks

Comment: yyyy/mm/dd is folder structure or naming convention of file ?

Comment: folder structure

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, to avoid the unnecessary customization, your best shot it to plan and create the library with **Document Set** structure (See: [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Document-Sets-c49c246d-31f1-4bfe-afe2-e26698b47e05)). Why? Simply because it seems you are relying on metadata on a library structure.  Not to get into its advantages/disadvantages ([1.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88055/when-should-document-sets-be-used-instead-of-folders-and-vice-versa), [2.](https://harmon.ie/blog/hidden-power-document-sets-sharepoint), [3.](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/document-sets-making-your-metadata-shine)) furthermore, you could have the archiving done with different **Views**. By creating a view, which e.g. filters the items to "`[Created] [more than] [year ago]`", you don't have to run any program on the background.

If you need to actually move the items to another location (say e.g. because of permission reasons), you could rely on either a workflow or a background program which moves the items from path A to path B.

Answer (score 0):

You can create policy to move the document to another location. Follow this post to create new policy : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakhiguha/2015/09/11/sharepoint-data-retention-policy/

Event needs to be set to : Created Date +  1 Year

Action : Transfer to another location (You can select from configured Send To locations that will send the document to a content organizer)